# AWS SFTP VPC Internet Facing endpoint unable to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, aws-sftp

First of all,  I have gone through forum and read around this but still no luck so posting .

I have created SFTP Server in VPC with Internet facing end point . It has got everything i.e
deployed in 2 private subnet , 2 Elastic IP attached to each ENI in private subnet , Interface endpoint with custom security group which allow SSH traffic on port 22 from specific IP's and tried any where too. Created user with private keys and public key uploaded to SFTP server .

However it is not able to connect from SFTP client ( WINscp) . It getting timed out . I have checked and ensured endpoint security group allow SSH over 22 but still no luck .

Basically followed this blog ( exclude VPC peering which I don't need )

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/use-ip-whitelisting-to-secure-your-aws-transfer-for-sftp-servers/

Can someone please help on this .

Comment: So the endpoints are in private subnets?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: VPC interface endpoint is created which is linked to 2 Private subnets where SFPT server is deployed and VPC endpoint has got security group which allow SSH traffic on port 22 from anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Aha, worked in the end . Initially SFTP servers were created in private subnets so changed to public subnets and it worked.